# как в vscode сделать, чтобы в SASS были подсказки классов?

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, visual-studio-code, sass

как в vscode сделать, чтобы в SASS были подсказки классов?  просто у меня их нет, а в обычном css показывает , а тут даже уже написанные классы не подсказывает

Answer (score -1):

Использовать eCSStractor. Подсказок не будет зато можно классы разом скопировать и вставить куда надо и как надо.

Comment: Это не ответ на вопрос.